# Publish office 365 MS Word AddIn

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, add-in, publish

I followed the documentation on https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Deploy-Office-Add-ins-in-the-Office-365-Admin-Center-737e8c86-be63-44d7-bf02-492fa7cd9c3f to publish a created addin to our users. Unfortunately it is not showing up when users check out their Add Inns ( I see a caption Office 365 / Managed by admin but no selectable addin.

I tried:

- Restarted MS Word
- Logging in and out from MS Word does not help.
- Removing the add in and adding again (through file or URL both not work)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today I had a support engineer of Microsoft on the phone about my case and they  resolved the issue.  I can  deploy add-ins again.

Answer (score 1):

We seem to have the same issue; If you intercept the HTTPS traffic (by Fiddler for instance), do you see a 500 response to the 'POST /ews/exchange.asmx' with the body containing 'GetPrivateCatalogAddIns'?

So far, this seems to be an issue with Exchange internals. We've been trying to get into contact with Microsoft about the issue. [Here you can find the StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43892893/add-ins-do-not-show-up-under-admin-managed-after-deploying-them-to-the-office) issue we have filed, and [Here you can find the question on the MS fora](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_o365admin-mso_other/how-can-i-add-an-admin-managed-add-in-to-word/c04e3254-586a-42b4-8520-53699cccbcb9?tm=1494422579532).

EDIT: It was confirmed that this was indeed an internal problem. We have removed our deployed plug-ins and added them again. The call now responds with a 200 and everything seems to be working again.

Unfortunately, we also found out that there is an issue with the Add-in registration interface in the Office 365 Admin Centre, as people who are not full administrator but User management administrator instead can no longer upload Add-ins due to an Exchange credential error. A Office 365 Administrator however can and this seems to be working with us.

Comment: thanks! I also have a ticket filed at Microsoft and had some remote sessions to reproduce. MS is also not able to deploy my manifest on their own domain. So there is an issue.. keep you posted here.